# How to set Request Header in Property transfer step in Soap UI using JsonPath

Tags: soapui

Im trying to set request header using property transfer step, but could not get anyway to access headers using `JsonPath`.

What to write in highlighted section to access request headers using *jsonPath*

[image]

Please help...

Response structure in Source:

```
   {  
      "payload": {
         "content": {
            "reason": "token successfully created",
            "success": "true",
            "authDetails": {
               "accessToken": "MyaccesToken",
               "expiresIn": "My ExpiryTime",
               "refreshToken": "MyRefreshToken"
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

Request structure in Target field

```
GET https://Myendpoint/myresouce/etc HTTP/1.1

Header1: myHeader1Value
Header2: **<Im trying to assign "MyaccessToken" in above step to this header>**
```

Comment: Can you show json response and what header you want to add? is it only for next request?

Comment: @Rao - The Json path in source field is working properly, I'm able to see the value being picked when I run the step. Accessing header of Request in target field is my issue. what is the jsonpath i can use to assign the value to any header in the Request of target field?

Comment: Would you mind providing the requested info, please?

Comment: @Rao..  Please see the edits to question for details

Comment: Thank you for the update. So, you need the token only next step or for all the tests?

Comment: yes.. I would like to achieve this using property transfer... instead of using script.

Comment: Naresh, can you please check the solution to see if that helpful? By the way are you using SoapUI free version or Pro software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here how you could achieve this:

- Create custom property say `TOKEN` at project level.
- In the property transfer step, use *Target* as `Project name`, and select `TOKEN` for *Property*.
- For the request, click on header; provide name as required and value as `${#Project#TOKEN}`
- You can do the same for each request for which the same header is needed.

Comment: Thank you the answer...  I knew I could achieve it this way... but I dont want to put token as a project level property.. I would like to see if this is achievable using just property transfer...

Comment: Sorry. That is using property transfer only, isn't? The reason to store the token at project level is that all the suites needs this token in order to authenticate your requests. Would appreciate if you try the solution and see if that resolves the issue and be able to proceed with your testing successfully.

Comment: @Nareshsadu, would mind providing your input after trying the above solution? You must understand the someone has spend their time for your problem. Appreciate upvotes for helpful answers and accept it as answer if you think that is best solution to resolve the issue.

Comment: upvoted.. My project uses multiple tokens based on grant types and I do not want to store all of them as project properites, so I want to see if it is possible to assign it to header of request in propertyTransfer step using jsonPath/XmlPath notaion....

Comment: Should not be a problem if there are multiple tokens, store them as something like `USERNAME_TOKEN` or `TOKEN1` etc., What you say does not help if the same token should be used across multiple suites or cases.  Isn't it? Do you have any other solution which is better and workable? Do you have any other reason such that above solution can't be applied to your case?

Comment: I completely agree with you.. I want to handle the tokens in clean manner instead of storing them with different keys in properties.... Im just curious to know if it is impossible to do it the way, I want to do it as described in the question. I'll wait some more time, for somebody to comment on this, and if not, I'll mark this as an answer...

Comment: @Nareshsadu, If you look at bottom(target section) the Property Transfer step, you do not see to add them as headers. So, you can't be able to achieve what you are saying, IMO. For a moment, let us assume you can add to the header for specifict test step, then how do you want add the header for the rest of the test steps? Just think of it.

Comment: finally I could see the reponse property in "property transfer step" does hold only reponse body/content not headers. accepting your answer. Thank you, for your help.

Comment: I found this answer; it matches one on the smarbear forums.  I believe I have the request and transfer steps set correctly - the value shows up in the property.  Can you elaborate on the syntax of the value?  You say to use `project` whereas the forum post says `TestCase`. What should I be using?

Comment: It's up to you. It is mentioned `Project` level in the answer as generate token once and use it across the test suites/ test cases. If you store it a `TestCase`, you may not be able access it in another test case easily. And it may not make sense, I believe.

Comment: We can set up properties on different levels. For example: Global level, Project level, Test Suit level, Test Case level and Test Step level.

You can access the property value by using the following:
${#Global#key}
${#Project#key}
${#TestSuite#key}
${#TestCase#key}
${TestStepProperty#key}

References: https://youtu.be/N_ahq1dwQmI?feature=shared